# pandas dataframe adding a value to one member of a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

We have the following dataframe (`df`) that has 3 columns. The goal is to make sure that the summation of "Load" for  **each group based on IDs**  is equal to 1. I think we can do this using `groupby`

`Num   ID  Load
1   AEC 0.2093275
2   AEC 0.5384086
3   CIZ 0.1465657
4   CIZ 0.7465657
5   CIZ 0.1465657`

If a group's total load is less than 1, we want to add or subtract from the group (by adding or subtracting from the load of all (proportionally) or one member of the group) to make the summation equal 1 without adding extra rows to the dataframe (just by modifying the values).

Any help, **especially in the second part of the question**, is highly appreciated.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'AEC', 0.2093275], [2, 'AEC', 0.5384086],
                   [3, 'CIZ', 0.1465657], [4, 'CIZ', 0.7465657],
                   [5, 'CIZ', 0.1465657]], columns=['Num', 'ID', 'Load'])

df_grouped = df.groupby('ID').Load.agg(['count', 'sum']).reset_index()
df_grouped['change'] = (1 - df_grouped['sum']) / df_grouped['count']
change_map = df_grouped.set_index('ID')['change'].to_dict()

df.Load = df.Load + df.ID.map(change_map)

# df
#    Num   ID      Load
# 0    1  AEC  0.335459
# 1    2  AEC  0.664541
# 2    3  CIZ  0.133333
# 3    4  CIZ  0.733333
# 4    5  CIZ  0.133333
```

Comment: Is it possible to add just to one of the elements in each group rather than adding/subtracting to/from all members of each group?

Comment: @Ali, out of interest any reason why you un-accepted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [            
['AEC', 0.2093275],
['AEC', 0.5384086],
['CIZ', 0.1465657],
['CIZ', 0.7465657],
['CIZ', 0.1465657],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Load'])

groups = df.groupby('ID').agg({'ID': 'count', 'Load': 'sum'})

groups = groups.rename(columns = {'ID': 'Count', 'Load': 'Total'}).reset_index()

groups['adjust'] = (1 - groups['Total'])/groups['Count']

df = pd.merge(df, groups, on = 'ID')

df['Load'] = df['Load'] + df['adjust']

df = df.drop(['Total', 'Count', 'adjust'], axis = 1)

print(df)

#output

    ID      Load
0  AEC  0.335459
1  AEC  0.664541
2  CIZ  0.133333
3  CIZ  0.733333
4  CIZ  0.133333
```

Update code based on comment. Calculate an adjustment field based on a summarized dataframe. Then apply to adjustment evenly to each group.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work for me because you are actually adding a row to the dataframe. I want to actually subtract or add a value to one of the Loads in the group to make the group total to equal 1. How would you do that?
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Is it possible to add just to one of the elements in each group rather than adding/subtracting to/from all members of each group?

Comment: @Ali, it certainly is possible - feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I added the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533538/modify-value-of-pandas-dataframe-groups